# Predict output between 0 and 1 from three features (floats)

Tags: machine-learning

I've tried asking this before but I understand that I didn't provide enough information. I'm giving it another shot and will be more thorough.

I'm trying to set up a machine learning model that will return a value between 0 and 1 based on 3 numerical features. I don't have a lot of data yet but I'm working on getting more. Here is a snap of how the data looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFqZV.jpg

For example if I imput the following:

-Low: 1.78 -Medium: 2.30 -High: 0.89
It would output: 0.34 (just an example)

Would a classifier be a good option here?

Thanks in advance and please do let me know if I'm missing any important information.

Comment: Look up binary prediction algorithms. I would recommend starting with a Random Forest. They are easy to set up and require practically no data preprocessing. That being said, this question is still off topic for this site. It *may* be better suited on another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a number between 0 and 1, that gives you an estimate of the likelihood that it belongs to a given class, a good choice would be to use a probabilistic classifier. The classical methods for this would be logistic regression and naive bayes. Methods like SVM and decision trees don't necessarily give you a probability as output, but you can apply platt scaling to get a (possibly distorted) probability scale. A NN with a sigmoid output function can also work for this purpose, but I don't recommend it since you don't have a lot of data.